# Will Jobs.SO include intern jobs in the future?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I am a student and I believe there are many other students on SO. I just searched "intern" in the jobs section to find no intern jobs at all. I wonder if there will be intern jobs in the future? If so, when?

Answer (score 29):

Update: We now offer the ability to search by "Internship" and are actively campaigning to bring more internships to our site. All positions are paid.

[image]

---

You can enter `seniority:student` into the keyword field to see jobs for students. We're currently developing some updates to make this feature a bit more accessible.

Comment: Are there any conversations inside Stack Exchange about unpaid internships, and whether they will be permitted in different locations? Some jurisdictions effectively have outlawed unpaid internships unless they are of short duration. I wonder if some guidelines as to what SE will support, for a job advertiser audience, would be a good idea (if this does not already exist)?

Comment: @halfer just curious, have you seen unpaid internships on the site? We don't have a stated policy, but the internal consensus seems to be that we don't receive many or any unpaid internship listings.

Comment: No, just wondering if they will come in the future, especially if the site is to change to accommodate them.

Comment: @halfer As Donna said, we don't have a stated policy, but this was a good kick in the seat to create one.  So we're on it.  We'll update here and in our House rules once it's fleshed out.

Comment: That's great, thanks Donna and @WillCole! I am suspicious of them generally, reflecting the EU view that they are an attempt to get free work out of juniors and/or that they are only open to folks who are able to self-fund. There are probably some legal compliance issues too. However I am wanting to be sensitive to the possibility that they may still be considered useful in some jurisdictions, so perhaps short-durations only might be useful guideline starting point.