# Can't find Intern job by searching in Jobs.SO

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

This is a follow-up question of [Will Jobs.SO include intern jobs in the future?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332094/will-jobs-so-include-intern-jobs-in-the-future).

Today, I come across [a intern job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/126226/software-engineer-internship-imc-financial-markets?med=clc&ref=large-sidebar-tag-themed-java) when browsing a question on SO. But when I try to search more intern jobs, I can't even find the original one in ['seniority:student' search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=seniority%3Astudent&rs=1) or just ['internship' search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&searchTerm=internship). I also tried to search with location as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327740/job-search-doesnt-appear-to-return-all-results) suggested but also fails.

Is there something wrong with searching of job?

Answer (score 4):

This job has been marked with seniority of `Student` but it is currently targeted to only be visible to candidates that are:

- geo-located in Europe

  or
- have any country in Europe in their match preferences

If neither of those are true then the job is hidden from searches and browsing the job board. If you have the link to the job, maybe from Twitter or a Google search you can still visit it directly.

Your IP address does not resolve to Europe and your [match preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) do not contain any countries in Europe, so the job doesn't appear when you search for it in /jobs.